# Take a list of elements, insert non-unique elements, then return a list of lists of three elements.

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm starting to feel bad for [Furken Guzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5521628/furkan-g%C3%BCzel), with regard to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723548/in-python-python-programmin-how-to-create-it-with-for-loop-thank-you-for-now) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714975/copy-new-list-should-be-unique) so I'm going to try to ask the question he is trying to ask, and then answer it.

I *think* what he wants to do it take a list, remove the duplicate elements while otherwise maintaining the ordering of the elements, then output those elements as a lists of 3 items, within a larger list.

so, for example:

```
input: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G']
output: [ ['A', 'B', 'C']
          ['D', 'E', 'F']
          ['G']           ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output_list, temp_list, list_two = [], [], []
input_list = [...]
for element in input_list:
    if element not in list_two:
         list_two.append(element)

for index, val in enumerate(list_two, start=1):
    temp_list.append(val)
    if index % 3 == 0:
        output_list.append(temp_list)
        temp_list = []

if temp_list:
    output_list.append(temp_list)
```